# How to yield a nested IENumerable?

Tags: c#, methods, yield

I know how to yield values in a method with return value `IENumerable`

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetDigits()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 1;
    yield return 1;
}
```

but how is the correct Syntax for a nested `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`?

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetNestedDigits()
{
    yield return yield return 1; //??
}
```

Comment: You have to yield an `IEnumerable`  if you want to yield the actual values then you'd need another method to call to do that, like `yield return GetDigits();`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to return an IEnumerable using an *iterator*, create a *different* method that returns the IEnumerable. Otherwise just return eg `new []{1}`

Comment: There is no such thing as a nested yield. You are probably asking about *nested iterators* which answers itself - call another iterator method. This can be a lambda or a separate method. If the inner enumerables come from a database or collection though, you don't need to nest anything'

Comment: F.e.: `yield return Enumerable.Repeat(1, 3); yield return Enumerable.Repeat(1, 3); ...`

Comment: @c0rs please explain what you *actually* want to do. What you ask will force you to use a double loop to get at the individual items. Is this what you really want? Where does the inner enumerable come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot directly nest the `yield return` statements. You'd have to create another method:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetNestedDigits()
{
    yield return GetNestedEnumerable();
}

public IEnumerable<int> GetNestedEnumerable()
{
    yield return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetNestedDigits()
{
    yield return new List<int>
    {
        1
    };
}
```

Comment: That's not a nested yield. That's a single yield which returns a list, not an IEnumerable

Comment: No need for a list, a `new []{1}` is enough and I don't think the OP wanted to return a concrete collection

Comment: @Kenneth there is no such thing as a nested yield in the way you mean. That *is* an IEnumerable that contains `IEnumerable<int>`. The OP should probably ask for a *nested iterator*, not a nested yield.

Comment: Yes, but it's creating the list when it accesses the nested list. As soon as you access the outer Enumerable, it will create the List with all its items. That's not what the OP wants. He wants the inner Enumerable to be created through yield as well. I'm guessing his `yield return 1` is just an example

Comment: @Kenneth that's a problem with the question's wording, not this answer. The OP should explain what he *really* wants to do, because if eg the inner IEnumerable comes from another collection or the database, there's no need to use another iterator

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OK, you're right, but if you read the question, you can see what he means. The actual terminology may be of, but if you read his pseudo-code his intentions are quite clear

Answer (score 0):

If I take all your text literally you can do this using:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetNestedDigits()//{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}
{
  yield return new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
  yield return new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

You have to declare some sort of collection that implements IEnumerable and return that. You can't directly nest yields. Maybe a closer way would be to declare private IEnumerables which you then return.

```
IEnumerable<int> GetNestedDigitsA()
{
  yield return 1;
  yield return 2;
  yield return 3;
}

IEnumerable<int> GetNestedDigitsB()
{
  yield return 1;
  yield return 2;
  yield return 3;
}

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetNestedDigits()//{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}
{
  yield return GetNestedDigitsA();
  yield return GetNestedDigitsB();
}
```